# (node:15864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-window

when I run the below command to convert exe to appx, we faced below error:

**Command**

```
electron-windows-store --input-directory <path to folder containing electron
executable> --output-directory <path> --package-version “0.0.1” --package-name “PackageName” --package-executable <path to folder containing electron
executable> --manifest <path to custom manifest> --assets <path to assets folder>
```

**Error**

```
(node:15864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
at inquirer.prompt.then.then (C:\Users\kkannan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-windows-store\lib\params.js:86:29)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

 (node:15864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

 (node:15864) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I think adding a minimal example that reproduces this behaviour gives you a better chance to receive an answer that actually helps you :) Like this you have wait for someone with a good hunch or who ran in this too.